# Integrated blocks for thesis structure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to draw jigsaw blocks (boxes) and then write text into it. Something like the following figure.

[image]

I could not find a package to get this shape, however, I am posting a minimal example with rectangle shapes.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning,patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    
%
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance=0 cm,outer sep = 0pt]
    %
    \tikzstyle{introStyle}=[rectangle,draw, minimum width=4 cm, minimum height=3.5cm, anchor=north west,fill=red!20]
    \tikzstyle{lrStyle}=[rectangle,draw, minimum width=4 cm, minimum height=3.5cm, anchor=north west,fill=green!20]
    \tikzstyle{methodStyle}=[rectangle,draw, minimum width=8 cm, minimum height=3.5cm, anchor=north west,fill=blue!20]
    %
    \node[introStyle] (intro) at (0,0) {
        \parbox{3.5cm}{\color{red}%
            \begin{itemize}
            \item context
            \item research problem
            \item objectives 
            \end{itemize}
        }
    };
    %   
    \node[lrStyle] (lr) [right = of intro] {
        \parbox{3.5cm}{\color{green}%
            \begin{itemize}
            \item studies before 2000
            \item studies after 2000
            \end{itemize}
        }
    };
    %
    \node[methodStyle] (method) at (0,-3.5) {
        \parbox{3.5cm}{\color{blue}%
            \begin{itemize}
            \item method
            \item set up
            \end{itemize}
        }
    };
    %
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%    
\end{document}
```

Here is my result, however, I would like to have jigsaw blocks rather than rectangle.

**Edit after comments**

1. I would like to get blocks with two different sizes as shown here (red/green box and blue box)
2. In my case, I just need one dent (bump/notch) on bottom of red and green boxes so that they are embedded into blue box.

[image]

Comment: Are the sizes of the blocks uniform or they can too change sizes?

Comment: No, they are not. I would like to get blocks with at least two different sizes as shown above. Red and green boxes embedding into blue.

Comment: so the bottom one would have two dents or bumps (or whatever they are called)? Can you please clarify your requirements in that sense so that efforts are not wasted?

Comment: thanks @percusse. I have entered my requirements to the post.

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/puzzle/

Comment: @EladDen thanks for the pointer, I will give it a shot.

Comment: With the example above, I could make only this, https://www.overleaf.com/5521991ptshby#/17733814/. Can someone explain or give another point to understand whatever inside the definition `\drawPuzzleSide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after looking on [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/puzzle/) and other references, I think, it is too difficult for me than needed. So, I fixed it by using arrow and rectangle...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning,patterns,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance=0 cm,outer sep = 0pt,inner sep=0pt]
    %
    \def\x{0.4\textwidth}
    \def\y{0.35\textwidth}

    \tikzstyle{introStyle}=[rectangle,  minimum width=\x, minimum height=\y, anchor=north west, fill=red!20]
    \tikzstyle{lrStyle}=[rectangle, minimum width=\x, minimum height=\y, anchor=north west, fill=green!20]
    \tikzstyle{methodStyle}=[rectangle,  minimum width= 2*\x, minimum height=\y, anchor=north west, fill=blue!20]

    \node[methodStyle] (method) at (0,-\y) { % plotting it first, in order to overlaid by other rectangle/arrows.
        \parbox[c]{5cm}{%
            \begin{itemize}
            \item method
            \item set up
            \end{itemize}
        }
    };
    %
    \node[introStyle] (intro) at (0,0) {
        \parbox[c]{4cm}{%
            \begin{itemize}
            \item context
            \item research problem
            \item objectives 
            \end{itemize}
        }
    };
    \draw[-Triangle, line width=.22cm,red!20] (\x/2,-\y) - - (\x/2,-1.18*\y) ;
    %
    \node[lrStyle] (lr) [right = of intro] {
        \parbox[c]{4cm}{%
            \begin{itemize}
            \item studies before 2000
            \item objectives 
            \item 
            \end{itemize}
        }
    };
    \draw[-Triangle,  line width=.22cm,green!20] (1.5*\x,-\y) - - (1.5*\x,-1.18*\y) ;

    % outer rectangle
    \draw [densely dashed] (0,0) rectangle (2*\x,-2*\y);
    %
    %
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is output...

[image]

This is not exactly what is described above but good enough given the time and effort required. Hopefully, useful for others too.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `jigsaw` package to create such shapes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{jigsaw}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tiny
\sffamily

\begin{scope}
    \color{blue!40!white}
    \piece[blue!40!white]{-1}{-1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \color{green!30!white}
    \piece[green!30!white]{1}{1}{0}{1}
\end{scope}   
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \color{green!30!white}
    \piece[green!30!white]{0}{1}{0}{-1}
\end{scope}    
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \color{orange}
    \piece[orange]{-1}{0}{0}{-1}
\end{scope}       

\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
    \color{green!50!black}
    \piece[green!50!black]{0}{-1}{1}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \color{brown}
    \piece[brown]{0}{0}{-1}{1}
\end{scope}   
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \color{blue}
    \piece[blue]{0}{1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}    
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,yshift=-1cm]
    \color{blue!25!white}
    \piece[blue!25!white]{0}{0}{1}{-1}
\end{scope}      

\node at (0.5,0.5) {Abstract};
\node at (2,0.5) {Literature Review};
\node at (3.5,0.5) {Discussion};

\node at (0.5,-0.5) {\color{white}Introduction};
\node at (1.6,-0.5) {Methods};
\node at (2.4,-0.5) {\color{white}Results};
\node at (3.5,-0.5) {Conclusions};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]